# Unable to hide parts of my page, but the same code works on JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, razor

I'd like to use toggle() (or hide()) from jquery, but it doesn't work.

I know the syntax I use is not bad. It works on  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hNzn3/2/), but I'm unable to make it work with the razor view.

Here is the code I wanted to use :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".hidden").toggle();
    </script>

@Using Html.BeginForm(IsPost)
@Html.ValidationSummary(True)
@<fieldset>
    <legend>contact</legend>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td><h3>@Html.Raw("Données personnelles : ")</h3></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>@Html.Raw("Nom : ")</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.nom)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.nom)</td>

        <td>@Html.Raw("Prénom : ")</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.prenom)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.prenom)</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td class="hidden">@Html.Raw("Date de naissance : ")</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.dateNaissance)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.dateNaissance)</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
End Using
```

The html code that is generated is the following :

```
 <tbody><tr>
        <td><h3>Données personnelles : </h3></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>Nom : </td>
        <td><input class="text-box single-line" id="nom" name="nom" value="" type="text">
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="nom" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></td>



        <td>Prénom : </td>
        <td><input class="text-box single-line" id="prenom" name="prenom" value="" type="text">
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="prenom" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td class="hidden">Date de naissance : </td>
        <td><input class="text-box single-line" id="dateNaissance" name="dateNaissance" value="" type="text">
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="dateNaissance" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></td>
        </tr>
```

And here are the CSS related to those spans :

```
        /* Styles for validation helpers
        -----------------------------------------------------------*/
        .field-validation-error {
            color: #ff0000;
        }

        .field-validation-valid {
            display: none;
        }

        .input-validation-error {
            border: 1px solid #ff0000;
            background-color: #ffeeee;
        }

        .validation-summary-errors {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #ff0000;
        }

        .validation-summary-valid {
            display: none;
        }

        /* Styles for editor and display helpers
        ----------------------------------------------------------*/
        .display-label, 
        .editor-label {
            margin: 1em 0 0 0;
        }

        .display-field, 
        .editor-field {
            margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
            position:relative;
            left:5px;
        }

        .text-box {
            width: 30em;
        }

        .multiline
        {
            height: 6.5em;
            position:relative;
            left:5px;
        }

        .tri-state {
            width: 6em;
        }
        .display-field
        {
            font-size:1.5em;
        }
```

What can I do to bypass all that stuff to make some parts of the page hidden?

Comment: Just put your script in [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: basic usage of jquery You need to wait DOM element ready `$(document).ready`

Comment: @ai.farfa: No, you don't. You just have to make sure your script runs *after* the DOM elements it needs to manipulate. This is easily done just by putting the script at the end of the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your code really is as quoted, the reason it works on jsfiddle and not in your code is that jsfiddle is including your script *after* the HTML, but your code is running the script *before* the elements exist in the DOM.

You have two choices:

1. Put your script at the *end* of the page, just before the closing `</body>` tag. I'd recommend this, [as do the YUI team](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html).
2. Use jQuery's [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) function (people frequently use the confusing shortcut for it, which is just [passing a function into the `jQuery` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3), which is usually aliased as `$`) to schedule your code to run on "DOM ready".

Answer (score 3):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".hidden").toggle();
});
    </script>
```

Comment: @patxy Only if you pass it a function, not if you pass it a selector.

Comment: ok thx, it does work like that. Weerd that it worked on jsFiddle. I though that toggle was the function

Comment: @patxy: This is one of the confusing bits of jQuery's API. If you pass a function into `$()`, it's a shortcut for `$(document).ready(...)`. The `$()` function is way overloaded (not only does it do completely unrelated things depending on whether you pass it a function or a string, it even does completely unrelated things depending on the *content* of strings you pass it).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need to use Javascript (or jQuery) for this. If you want the elements with the class `hidden` to be hidden initially, just use a CSS declaration:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I use it because this view has to be used in different contexts. So, in function of the action that called the view, some fields don't have to be displayed